# Padding a string in a standard detailTextLabel does not align as expected

Tags: swift, string

There must be something I have overlooked, or I dont get the behaviour of the string.padding(toLength: Int, withPad: String, startingAt: Int) at all.

I am using the standard cell in a tableView. I want to have a certain length before I add additional information in the subtitle of the Cell.
My issue is that the countries in the example below dont align.

I would expect:

```
Highlands      Scotland
Islay          Scotland
```

But I have:

```
Highlands      Scotland
Islay        Scotland
```

[image: The problem]

My code:

```
            let regionPadded = "\(whisky.region!)" //NB !!
            let regionPadded2 = regionPadded.padding(toLength: 30, withPad: "-", startingAt: 0)//NB !!
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = regionPadded2 + "\(whisky.country!)" //NB !!
            print(regionPadded2.count)
            print(cell.detailTextLabel?.text?.count)
```

Or simpler:

```
if whisky.region != "" {
        let regionPadded = "\(whisky.region!)" //NB !!
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = regionPadded.padding(toLength: 40, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)+"\(whisky.country!)" //NB !!
    }
    else {
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(whisky.country!)"  //NB !!
```

The strange thing is that the console prints the expected lengths...
 What am I missing?

Comment: That would only work if you were using a monospaced font (like courier).  A proportional font will give different widths for different characters ("i" takes up less width than "H").